# How to search into two table where they have different column

Tags: php, codeigniter

is there any way I can search the data of a table where I will use a two criteria Firstname and lastname?

**Table 1**

```
Firstname | LastName | Gender

| Donald | Trump | Male|
```

**Table 2**

```
GFirstName | GLastName | Gender

|Hillary| Clinton | Female

|Donald | McDonald| Female
```

in my case I would like to Search for **"Donald Trump"**

and MySQL data should show me info of

**table 1**

```
 Donald | Trump| Male
```

I tried using this query but it gives me nothing

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE 'Firstname' LIKE %Donald Trump%
  OR 'LastName' LIKE %Donald Trump%
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM table2 WHERE 'Firstname' LIKE %Donald Trump%
  OR 'LastName' LIKE %Donald Trump%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE 
         CONCAT (Firstname, ' ',LastName)  LIKE '%Donald Trump%' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM table2 WHERE CONCAT (Firstname, ' ',LastName)  LIKE '%Donald Trump%'
```

Comment: im using only one criteria only **Donald Trump** i cant separate **Donald**  and **Trump**

Comment: Thank you this solve the problem!! one more question what did  " CONCAT (Firstname, ' ',LastName) " actually did to make it work?

Comment: it concatenates the two columns and sees it as one column

Comment: Thanks!! why didnt i think of that. ! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change query like below, **put brackets in or condition**:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ('Firstname' LIKE %Donald Trump%
  OR 'LastName' LIKE %Donald Trump%)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM table2 WHERE ('Firstname' LIKE %Donald Trump%
  OR 'LastName' LIKE %Donald Trump%)
```

Comment: still not working, but if remove the **Trump**  inside the **Like** it gives me all the record that has a word **Donald** but my question is what if i have two words criteria **Donald** and **Trump** where i want to search on two different column and tables. what i really want by doing this is getting the data of **Donald Trump** **NOT** getting the data of **Donald Mcdonald** found in **table2**

Comment: @APaul It won't work because you have separate columns. What you have to do is: Add one more column that combines the firstname and last name, then search in that column. Make changes in table structure

Comment: its okey Pathik i already solved the problem Ghost already gave me the correct syntax. Thanks to you too